# Is there a way to find out how much data does a google data studio dashboard consume from BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I would like to know how much data does Data Studio consume from querying a View from BigQuery.

For example, if I have a dashboard that is getting its data from a View in  BigQuery, how much data would it be using?

I have tried to look at the usage logs of Big Query, but due to my lack of experience with the tools I have not been able to find a solution. I have been able to find specific bytes processed for the data(View from BigQuery) in question but don't know how much is from Data Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in BigQuery at the Query History you can search for queries that have used that view by typing in it's name.

Queries from Data Studio will have strange looking names e.g.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT t0.yourVariable) AS t0_qt_QqufHrYw
```

If you click on the query you will see the amount of data processed and billed (Bytes processed & Bytes billed).

Bare in mind that each component of your report will have it's own query (all at a similar time) so you may need to add them up to find the total bytes queried.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. That helps! So I do have the history in BigQuery as well. I can just use regex to find the “t0_qt_” along with the other variables i need. Right?

Comment: From looking at my history it seems the t0 part is pretty consistent but the variable name after that tends to vary so might miss some if used to filter. Using the view name would be the best idea

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Actually I was able to find another variable with the help of t0 that can help find all data studio specific queries. Thank you so much! You were a big help!

Comment: When in doubt use the [jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) method of the BigQuery API and look for the labels property, Datastudio jobs usually have a "datastudioenv" label.